# imagemapster altImage and hotspot strokes not aligning properly in ie9 & ie10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Using imagemapster.

I can't get altImage and hotspot strokes to align properly in ie9 & ie10. Mousingover does trigger my altImage and stroke, but, you'll see if you mouseover any of the orange "i" circles, in ie9 & ie10, my altImage and/or stroke is not aligned with my default image and appears toward the top of the page. It works perfectly in ie11 and up.

Here is the page in question: http://cjehost.com/qt/nipt/page5.php

Answer (score 0):

This had nothing to do with imagemapster. Once I deleted: canvas{height:auto;} from my stylesheet, the altImage and imagemap stroke/highlight worked pefectly.